# Python - convert time to hours and minutes, not seconds

Tags: python, datetime

```
Time1=`1:02:00`
```

When I try to do this:

```
Hrs = datetime.datetime.strptime((Time1), "%H:%M")
```

I recieve the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00
```

Is there any way that I can convert `Time1` to just hours and minutes, and 'ignore' the seconds?

Answer (score 4):

But you have seconds. So you must convert them, but you can replace them with 0:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('1:02:30','%H:%M:%S').replace(second=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are reading time value from a formatted string. If a string looks like H:MM:SS then it doesn't make sense to specify a different format. If you want to format the datetime value without seconds, it's possible with strftime:

```
>>> Time1="1:02:00"
>>> Hrs = datetime.datetime.strptime((Time1), "%H:%M:%S")
>>> print Hrs.strftime("%H:%M")
01:02
```